# session is identified in the primary folder but not in sub folders

Tags: php, session, path, session-cookies

[EDITED] I have this code at the top of every page in my site control panel (path is changed to ../ in ajax folder php file)

```
require 'session.php';
require 'db.php';
require 'check.php';
```

the session.php file contains this code

```
$lifetime=604800;
session_set_cookie_params($lifetime,'/site_controlpanel','localhost/site_folder',false,true);
ini_set('session.cookie_lifetime',604800);
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime',604800);
ini_set('session.use_trans_sid', false);
ini_set('session.use_only_cookies' , true);
session_start();
setcookie(session_name(),session_id(),time()+$lifetime);
echo $_SESSION['session1'];
```

the db.php contains database connection configurations 
the check.php contains this code

```
if(isset($_SESSION['session1']) && isset($_SESSION['session2'])){
    //do something
}
else{
    echo 'check.php file contains no sessions';
    ?><meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3;url=login.php"> <?php
}
```

this code is in all my control panel files and inside ajax folder files.
all my pages work fine I don't face any problem with sessions and I can print session values but files inside the ajax folder prints

```
"Notice: Undefined index: branchreal" 
"check.php file contains no sessions"
```

and don't recognize the session at all what could be the problem?

Comment: You are using `require` based on *relative path*, meaning that these files are in the current working folder. So if you have the three files in the primary folder, and try to include them from a subfolder, it will try to find those files in that subfolder.

Comment: You should replace the `.` with a `,` in your `session_set_cookie_params` function call - otherwhise the session lifetime is invalid

Comment: path is correct in ajax folder files i use '../'

Comment: changed to    ,    session works fine everywhere except in the ajax folder files